# Set up network connection in Hyper-V

Tags: linux, hyper-v, ip-address

I created several VMs on Hyper-V on a Windows 10 Pro Client with a wired USB Ethernet adapter. The Windows machine keeps its IP address after a restart, the Linux machine (Ubuntu Server) doesn't. Both are using the *Default Switch* (note: the external switch does not work on USB Ethernet adapters).

I noticed the Windows VM kept its MAC address, so I tried to change the MAC address for the Linux VM from *dynamic* to *static*. Unfortunately that did not help.

The goal is to establish an SSH connection between the host and the Linux VM (always via the same IP address). In addition to that I want the VM to have access to the Internet. Note: the host is a laptop therefore the Internet connection will be established through different LANs and through different interfaces (build in WLAN, different wired USB-LAN adapter on different docking stations, etc.)

**SOLUTION:**

Currently I'm looking at configuring an internal switch. This [setup suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67171821/2089396) relies on giving the internal switch static settings. Unfortunately it does not allow to set up a default gateway, so the VM can't use the *Hosts Internet* connection (at least I didn't find a solution to do that with the internal switch).

Note: I use 192.168.192.1/24 for the switch and 192.168.192.2/24 for the VM. I can ping the switch and the VM from the host and vice versa (ones I set the Windows firewall on the host appropriately).

To get simultaneous access the Internet (while using the internal switch to connect from the host to the VM via a non-changing IP address) I added a second network interface to the VM and set it to the default switch. I configured the second NIC to get its configuration via DHCP (via `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml`):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.192.2/24]
    eth1:
      dhcp4: true
```

`ip a` shows that it's up and running:

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:15:5d:97:34:01 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.192.2/24 brd 192.168.192.255 scope global eth0
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
   inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe97:3401/64 scope link
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
   link/ether 00:15:5d:97:34:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
   inet 192.168.204.131/28 brd 192.168.204.143 scope global dynamic eth1
      valid_lft 86333sec preferred_lft 86333sec
   inet6 fe80::215:5dff:fe97:3403/64 scope link
      valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Pinging the internal switch (`192.168.204.129`) works (mind the Windows firewall!), pinging an outside server, e.g., *8.8.8.8* works as well. Thanks to JW0914 for his suggestions in the comments!

Please also note John's answer. It wasn't appropriate for my case, but it gives you the nice bonus that the VM is reachable from the routers LAN (and not only from the host).

Comment: The sole purpose of the `Default Switch` is to provide WAN access only and won't provide a static IP _(Microsoft made this change a few years ago to make Hyper-V VM setup simpler, as previously an External switch had to be created in Switch Manager)_. Depending on why you need a static IP: **(1)** to have the router assign the static IP, create an External switch [@John's answer]; **(2)** to allow client and host communication for RDP, file sharing, etc., create an Internal switch [Switch Manager]; **(3)** to allow VMs to communicate with one another, create a Private switch [Switch Manager]

Comment: @JW0914 you are correct, I do have a specific need here, which is to establish an SSH connection between host and VM (using the same IP) and I want the VM to have access to the internet.

Comment: You can go about that two ways, depending on whether you want the traffic to go through the router [external switch only], or whether you want Hyper-V to manage all traffic locally on the host [Default switch and Internal Switch], with the latter being how I have mine setup.

Comment: @JW0914 I tried the internal switch solution, unfortunately it doesn't work (see update to the question)

Comment: For the internal adapter's properties [`ncpa.cpl`], did you manually set it's IP and subnet mask _(those are the only two things that should be set on both client and host)_? If so, check the firewall on host and client, as that's how my Ubuntu VM is configured and host `<->` client communication works fine. Verify if it's all traffic or just pinging that's blocked, as ping is blocked by default, but you should be able to SSH into it, connect via RDP, etc..

Comment: @JW0914 i got the ping working both sides now. What should I use as gateway for the Hyper-V switch and for the VM though?

Comment: @JW0914 yes for SSH between host and VM this will work but my VM is suppose to access the internet as well (see question)? (in regards to your second aspect: I made the subnet for the VM/switch is different then the subnets I'm connecting to with the host)

Comment: You would add the `Default` switch for internet access and the Internal switch to the VM's Properties _(Internal switch has no gateway - only the IP and Subnet Mask should be set)_. Depending on how organized you want the addressing to be, you may want to avoid using subnets normally used by routers [`192.168.1.0/24`, `2.0/24`, `3.0/24`, etc.] on Internal switches, else you'll run into issues when connecting to a router using the same subnet; e.g. I use a smaller subnet mask [`/28`, `/29`] with a [non-default IP range](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html) to keep addressing sane.

Comment: @JW0914 so the conclusion is that I can't have a "non-changing" IP on the VM and internet access at the same time?

Comment: **([Example](https://imgur.com/a/xVEeK6P))** You'll have two adapters [switches] with two different IPs - the `Default` switch will have a dynamically allocated `172.x.x.x` IP for providing WAN access and the Internal switch will have whatever IP and Subnet Mask you set on each OS _(must be manually configured on the host and the client OSes since it doesn't have a Gateway/DHCP server)_

Comment: @JW0914 doh, sometimes you are just to deep inside the problem...  thanks a lot for your hint, adding a second network card did the trick - of course. Feel free to use my last part to write an answer if you want the reputation (otherwise I'll do it myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sole purpose of the [Default Switch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171113-what-s-new-in-hyper-v-for-windows-10-fall-creators-update#default-switch) is to provide WAN access and won't provide a static IP by design:

- Microsoft made this [change](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/community/team-blog/2017/20171113-what-s-new-in-hyper-v-for-windows-10-fall-creators-update) a few years ago to make Hyper-V VM setup simpler, as previously an External switch had to be created in Switch Manager, and provides access to the host’s network regardless of connection type

Depending on why a static IP is needed, create in [Virtual Switch Manager](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines#create-a-virtual-switch-by-using-hyper-v-manager) or [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines#create-a-virtual-switch-by-using-windows-powershell):

<sup>***Traffic managed by router:***</sup>

- ***External* switch:** router assigns static IP *(@John's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1661913/529800))*

  - Create one for [both](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/connect-to-network#the-two-switch-approach) ethernet and WiFi, as VMs do not auto-switch between wired/wireless

<sup>***Traffic managed by host:***</sup>

- ***Internal* switch:** manually assign IP subnet on host and client

  - Allows communication between VM ⟷ host and/or VM ⟷ VM
  - Lacks DHCP server and Gateway, so only the IP and [subnet mask](https://www.aelius.com/njh/subnet_sheet.html) would be set 
     [image: Example] 
     Avoid using subnets normally used by routers [`192.168.1.0/24`, `2.0/24`, `100.0/24`, etc.], else issues will occur when connecting to a router using the same subnet
- ***Private* switch:** manually assign IP subnet on clients

  - Allows VM ⟷ VM communication that is isolated from host's traffic

---

[**Virtual Switch Manager:**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines#create-a-virtual-switch-by-using-hyper-v-manager)

1. *Hyper-V Manager* → *Actions* → *Virtual Switch Manager*
2. *New virtual network switch* → *Create virtual switch* → <type> → *Create Virtual Switch*
3. Create a *Name* → Select *Connection type* → *OK*/*Apply*

[**PowerShell:**](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/virtualization/hyper-v/get-started/create-a-virtual-switch-for-hyper-v-virtual-machines#create-a-virtual-switch-by-using-windows-powershell)

1. <kbd>[image: WinKey]</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> → `powershell` → <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+*OK*
2. List existing network adapters and note the `Name` of the adapter to use:

   ```powershell
   PS $ Get-NetAdapter

     Name                      InterfaceDescription                    ifIndex Status       MacAddress             LinkSpeed
     ----                      --------------------                    ------- ------       ----------             ---------
     vWiFi                     Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #3          62 Up           A0-11-22-33-44-55        10 Gbps
     LAN                       Killer E2200 Gigabit Ethernet Controll…      25 Disconnected B0-11-22-33-44-55         0 bps
     BT                        Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Networ…      23 Disconnected B1-11-22-33-44-55         3 Mbps
     vLAN                      Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter             54 Up           A1-11-22-33-44-55        10 Gbps
     vDefault                  Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #2          58 Up           A2-11-22-33-44-55        10 Gbps
     OpenVPN TAP6              TAP-Windows Adapter V9                       12 Disconnected A3-11-22-33-44-55         1 Gbps
     OpenVPN WinTun            Wintun Userspace Tunnel                      11 Disconnected                         100 Gbps
     WiFi                      Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260           5 Up           B2-11-22-33-44-55     866.7 Mbps
     vShare                    Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapter #4           2 Up           A4-11-22-33-44-55        10 Gbps
   ```
3. Create virtual switch:

   - **External:**

     ```powershell
     New-VMSwitch -Name vWiFi  -NetAdapterName WiFi -AllowManagementOS $true
     ```
   - **Internal:**

     ```powershell
     New-VMSwitch -Name vShare -SwitchType Internal
     ```
   - **Private:**

     ```powershell
     New-VMSwitch -Mame vPrivate -SwitchType Private
     ```

Answer (score 3):

If you need guest machines to have the same IP address using Hyper-V, then set up the guest machines to have bridged networking. That will work, and usually applies to VMware as well. This is for one network.

Consider the environment you are using.

**One:**

A desktop computer with a classic wired Ethernet adapter is ideal for Bridged Networking (External Switch) where the Guest gets the IP address from the Router the host machine is attached to.

You would do this if you need to access a Guest machine. Bridged Network (External Switch) is ideal for this.

Here is a complete post for accessing a Guest machine using a Bridged (External) Networking approach.

[Accessing a Guest machine with Static IP](https://superuser.com/questions/1660364/how-to-connect-via-rdp-to-my-hyper-v-machine/1660424#1660424)

This will work on a Laptop in a fixed physical location where the Laptop has an Ethernet connection, a mainboard wireless card, and most USB wireless adapters installed into the machine.

You can never use a cellular USB wireless adapter for bridging.

**Two:**

Typical roaming laptops use NAT networking but then the IP address is not fixed (static). It can work, and I use it on one machine, just not guaranteed.

This is useful if you are moving a laptop around to multiple locations, say Home and Work.

The trick here is to make sure you check your Guest IP before accessing it.

To have bridged networking, you need to add that networking type to the Hyper-V Manager.

I have done this here using a Linux Guest machine (Kali) and it worked fine.

Open Hyper-V Manager and then Virtual Switch Manager and add an External (Bridged Network) Switch type. Give it a Name you will use in the Guest setup.

[image]

Once done, go to the Guest area in Hyper-V Manager,  Settings and go to the Network Adapter. Add the External adapter from the prior step.

Restart any Guests you change.

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I should have wrote that into my question as well: I tried to create an external switch while I was playing around with the settings but I can not bind it to the wired network card. The host is a Dell laptop with a docking station attached via USB C, the network adapter is integrated into the docking station. The only option I have is to bind it to the wireless card that is integrated directly on the motherboard. I'll try your solution anyway, but is there a way to bind it to the wired network adapter?

Comment: Even if the machine has wireless internet, you can still use it for External Network Switch. The adapter in the screenshots is wireless.

Comment: Also if you wish to use the Wired adapter, you would need to make this adapter default. Bridged networking looks to the router the host is attached to in order to get an IP. This works, and I have done. NAT is better for roaming laptops, but then the IP is not static.

Comment: @Albin AFAIK, the only way to pass through a USB network card if it doesn't show up in _Switch Manager_ is via RDP _(Show Options → Local Resources → Local devices and resources → More...)_, and even this may not work _(I've never tried it)_

Comment: A cellular USB card will never work as bridged. A USB wireless card should work. A wireless card on the mainboard (same thing) will work. An Ethernet card will work. So the environment needs to be worked out. What I posted above is working here. My post says Add an External switch. Yes, you cannot modify the default.

Comment: @John The `Default Switch` cannot be modified as it's hardcoded into Hyper-V _(I may be misinterpreting your use of "Default")_. Something you may want to consider to make the answer all-encompassing would be to list the reasoning _([paraphrased](https://superuser.com/questions/1661912/setup-network-connection-in-hyper-v#comment2546597_1661912))_ for what type of Switch to create for the static IP _(I upvoted your answer regardless)_

Comment: I have made an explanatory addition to my answer as you have suggested.

Comment: @John OK, I think I understand how this is working. It does keep its IP now, but the "new" problem: I needed the behaviour of the default network, which seems to set up a virtual LAN with it's own subnet and assigns an IP from that LAN to the VM. Right now my VM's IP depends on the lease from the DHCP server the host is connected to. If I connect the host (a laptop) to a different LAN the IP of the VM will change as well. But I need it to stay the same. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What I still don't understand is why Windows gets to keep it's IP with the default switch but Linux doesn't

Comment: If you have set up an External Switch, do not use the Default Switch. If is possible (Default Only) that Windows can keep an IP address if no changes are made, but Linux may not. You cannot rely upon this. Use an External Switch,

Comment: @John OK, but how do I prevent the VM from getting an IP through the DHCP the host connects to?

Comment: This is a bit difficult:  It you do not wish to use the Router the host is connected to, then you must use NAT (Internal) networking (mentioned in my answer). But then guest IP is NOT assured. If you wish guest IP to be assured (static) then you must use Bridged (External) networking.  You need to be governed by what you need to do. I have one laptop (stays in place) with Bridged  (External) networking and my other laptop is default NAT (Internal).

Comment: @John I updated my question to include my actual goal here. The problem is I want to do both: have a static VM IP for an SSL connection but assuring the internet connection for the VM at the same time (regardless of the hosts connects to the internet, the VM should always be able to use this connection internet access as well).

Comment: If you wish to access a VM remotely, you still need a Static Guest IP - I use this. Then you need a secure way to access the host machine. Your goal suggests a local environment with multiple routers - do I have that correct?  You can route between networks. My linked solution post comes pretty close to doing that. It becomes much harder if the guest is on a NAT (Internal) network.

Comment: @John half correct, since it's a portable laptop it's multiple local environments like work, home etc.

Comment: To do what you are trying to do, the Guest needs to be Bridged (External). Then you know the Router IP at home and the different Router IP at work. All this can and will work - just be aware of the different environments. If you bring the Company (work) server to your home, it will not automatically work but it can be made to work.

Comment: An external switch will route traffic through its router, whereas Internal & Private switches don't, routing traffic locally on the host. The `Default` switch will always assign a random, dynamically allocated `172.x.x.x` IP since that's the way it was hardcoded, as its sole purpose is only to provide WAN access to a VM, nothing more. The simplest solution is to use an Internal switch ([example](https://imgur.com/a/xVEeK6P)), unless the VM needs access to a router's LAN; in that case, an External switch would be used with a static IP set on the router for the switch and its _static_ MAC

Comment: @Albin - just to wrap up:  Accessing a guest from different networks (one of your goals) will work best with Bridged Networking. You need to your Host IP from the router you are on. Keep everything straight and it can all work. I do variations of this. If you are just accessing a guest from the Host machine, you can use Internal (NAT) but watch for guest IP changes.

Comment: @John not really sure what you mean, if I create a bridged network (external network) the VM will get it's IP from the router as well, thus changing every time when I connect to a different LAN. Did I miss anything? Note: I found a different solution hinted by JW0914 by adding a second network card (one for the internal one for the default switch). Although I would be interested in getting your solution to work I don't want to waste your time with an "additional solution".

Comment: You can use an Internal setup. I said that before. But the IP of the guest machine is not guaranteed. It works and I have used this. But you have to be aware of IP changes. Just confirm the IP before trying to access it. If you know what host IP you will get at the two locations, that eases the task of using External switch if you choose to do this.

Comment: @John thanks, yeah, that was my "initial problem": I want to avoid to confirm the IP before I access the VM. The whole point was not needing to use the Hyper-V console (to get the "new IP") before I connect via SSH - but again maybe I misunderstood your answer. However even it didn't solve my "problem" I learned a lot from your answer anyway, so you definitely deserves an upvote! Thanks a lot for your afford, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @John I offered JW0914 to write an answer, if he's not interested do you want to in cooperate the solution in your answer? Otherwise I would write an answer myself.

Comment: I made some significant changes to my answer along the way to accommodate  all the ideas I am familiar with. What changes would you like to see?

Comment: @John sorry, didn't get a notification about your message, but never mind my previous message, since JW decided to post his own answer after all. +1 for your answer, and thanks a lot for your effort!