# How to add a Static IP-Adress to a Virtual Machine in Hyper V to stop changing the ip adress when restarting the VM

Tags: remote-desktop, hyper-v, switch

I have two questions:

1. How can i set up a Static IP Adress on my virtual Machine, which is running on Windows 11 in Hyper v. Every time i do start The virtual Machine and write in the command Prompt"IP-Config" then i always have a different one.
2. I want to have via Remote Desktop,  Control Access to my virtual Machine Outside from the local network. In order to that, i need a port forwarding, so basically i need a static IP-Adress which i can add to the Port forwarding settings.

   The Question is, which Kind of Switch should i set up and give a Static IP Adress? should it be the External Switch or Internal Switch?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use static IP with the default switch.  This is a very painful fact and I have spent many fruitless hours trying to find a solution.

Eventually I wrote a program to automatically update the host file upon guest restarts, so I can use hostname instead of IP address to access the guest.

https://github.com/aaalgo/hyperv2hosts

Answer (score 1):

> how can i set up a Static IP Adress on my virtual Machine, which is
> running on Windows 11 in Hyper v. Every time i do start The virtual
> Machine and write in the command Prompt"IP-Config" then i always have
> a different one.

Open Hyper-V Manager, go to Network Settings, and add an external NIC switch that you can give a Static IP on your Router that your Host machine uses.

> My Second question is, i want to have via Remote Desktop Controll
> Acess to my virtual Machine Outside from the local network. In order
> to that, i need a port forwarding, so basically i need a static
> IP-Adress which i can add to the Port forwarding settings.

You would use a VPN or SSH connection or if your ISP allows Port Forwarding, you can try setting up that way.

Here is a solution you might find helpful

[Hyper V static IP external swtich](https://superuser.com/questions/1661912/set-up-network-connection-in-hyper-v/1661913#1661913)

Comment: what does "ISP" mean?

Comment: ISP is the company that provides you with Internet and you need determine if you a NAT connection or whether they will let you do port forwarding.

Comment: ISP stands for "[internet service provider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_service_provider)"

Answer (score 1):

If you also have control over the DHCP controller in your local network (Router, Firewall, ... whoever does DHCP for your devices), one option to make sure that the VM always gets the same IP address is to:

1. give the VM a static MAC address
2. configure your DHCP server to reserve a specific IP for the static MAC address of the VM