# HyperV internal network detected as Unidentified network and keeps resetting to public after reboot

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v

I use a HyperV internal network in order to allow file sharing access via SMB between my guest and host.  This was working fine for several years but I recently upgraded to windows 11 (clean install).

I setup the network in hyperv manager, set a static IP, but found the guest could not access the host.  In Powershell, I manually set the network to private, then everything started working.
However, this does not survive a reboot.

How can I get the network to show up as not "unidentified" or get the "private" setting to stick?

Through reading other posts regarding this, people have suggested setting a gateway, I tried this but it did not make a difference.
Others have suggested changing a setting to make all unidentified networks private, but this seems unsafe eventhough this is a desktop.
Some have suggested setup a script to run on startup but that isnt a very clean solution.

Comment: You may find many ideas in [article1](https://woshub.com/how-to-change-a-network-type-from-public-to-private-in-windows/) and [article2](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-unidentified-network-windows). Try the ones that apply and let me know.

Comment: The two articles refer to how to set a network as "private".  I've already done that.  My issue is that it reverts back

Comment: What I was suggesting was to find a method that sticks.Could you add to your post screenshots of the Hyper-V network switch definition and properties?

Comment: There arent really many settings, everything is default. Connection Type "Internal Network" VLAN ID is not checked. Under Extensions, "Microsoft Windows Filtering Platform" is unchecked and "Microsoft NDIS Capture" is checked. No other settings in the virtual switch manager. The virtual switch creates a virtual adapter. THIS is where the issue is. The only setting I changed was setting an IP address and a subnet mask. Everything else is default.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I get the network to show up as not "unidentified" or get the
> "private" setting to stick?

Between Guest and Host, this should work and does work fine for me: Windows 11 host, 2 Linux guest machines.

Perhaps the fastest way to sort this out is to build a new Hyper-V machine using the Internal Network setup. You should be able to set up connections that survive restart. Start with default Internal Switch DHCP for testing purposes.

See below: I have found the Hyper-V External Switch better for static IP setups.

In my case I have to start XRDP after a restart but that is not a Hyper-V thing.

Hyper-V in Windows 11 is an upgrade from Hyper-V in Windows 10 which is another reason to try a new guest machine to test.

I myself made new guest machines in my Windows 11 Hyper-V setup.

Try as I have suggested and also try (if you wish) the Hyper-V External Network setup.  This works better for static IP addressing.

I have always found Private Networking (Windows Host) to work properly.

[image: Windows 11 Hyper-V settings]

Also see:

[Static IP using External Switch](https://superuser.com/questions/1701567/how-to-add-a-static-ip-adress-to-a-virtual-machine-in-hyper-v-to-stop-changing-t)

> Open Hyper-V Manager, go to Network Settings, and add an external NIC
> switch that you can give a Static IP on your Router that your Host
> machine uses.

All the above works, I can access the machine from a remote machine, and I can exchange files.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152213/discussion-on-answer-by-john-hyperv-internal-network-detected-as-unidentified-ne); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.