# Connect 2 Virtualbox Guests running on separate hosts

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtualization

I have 2 Virtualboxes, each one on a seperate host. I can not figure out how to get them to talk to eachother. Either they cant grab an IPV4 address or if they do they cant ping eachother.

Both Hosts are Windows 10
Both Guests on Linux

Comment: Are the hosts connected to the same LAN? (Are they connected via Wi-Fi or Ethernet?)

Answer (score 0):

For major Virtual Machine apps (VBOX, VMware, Hyper-V), the default networking setup is NAT.

So then your guest on Machine A is on a very different network than your guest on Machine B.  I have the same setup here with VMware on one Windows 10 Pro Host and Hyper-V on a Windows 11 Pro Host.  Guests on both machines are Linux (Ubuntu and Kali).

For Guests to be able to see each other (ping each other), they need to be setup with Bridged Networking so that the Guests see the router that the Host is connected to.

Change the networking type in the VBOX guest and restart the machine.

Here is a solution in Super User that shows a two machine setup with Windows 10 on one host accessing a Kali machine on the the other host.

[Connect one machine to other by RDP](https://superuser.com/questions/1660364/how-to-connect-via-rdp-to-my-hyper-v-machine/1660424#1660424)

The assumption here is that the Hosts are on the same network (same router / same ISP). If not, you need to connect the Host machines with VPN or like secure connection.

Comment: Hey John, even in bridged mode my 2 Linux guests do not grab an IPV4 Address

Comment: Make sure your router is set to hand out IPv4 addresses and make sure after you change to bridged networking that you restart the guests (actually shut down hosts and restart both).  I have this here and bridged networking works fine and is stable.  Also the machines should be on the same network / ISP or if different, must be connected by secure VPN or like.

Comment: My physical router (If thats what your talking about) does hand out IPV4. Although, is there anything I need to change in my Host Windows environments to let the Linux Guests communicate?

Comment: You need Network Discovery enabled and for sharing folders, File and Print sharing enabled.  Do this and check for Windows 10 connectivity before setting up the guests.

Comment: Also make sure on a small internal network (assumption here) that all devices are IPv4 (you do not need to disable and should not disable IPV6)