# Connecting to a Windows 10 share via its DNS hostname or IP address

Tags: windows-10, network-shares, file-sharing, smb, cifs

I have two Win 10 Home machines, both signed in to the same Microsoft account. Both machines use a password sign-in. TLDR: Accessing a public share via its DNS hostname or IP address fails.

Details: let's say that the first machine's system name is "Accounting". Accounting gets a DHCP assignment to a fixed IP address that resolves via DNS, backwards and forwards, to "`accounting.example.com`". Accounting has a publicly shared folder, "Shared".

The second machine is "`Roaming`", `Roaming` is a guest VM, running on a virtual subnet, NATed to the LAN, with the host serving DHCP to the `Roaming` guest, setting it up to the same DNS server. There are no firewalls between the two subnets, just a virtual NAT router.

From `Roaming`: using file explorer to browse to `\\accounting.example.com\Shared`: I am prompted for login and password. I supply the Microsoft account login and password, get "The specified network password is incorrect". From "More Details" all I get is: Error code: 0x80004005, "Unspecified Error". Running "Diagnose" tells me the same: "You don't have permission to access the share". `\\Accounting\Shared` hangs for a while and doesn't connect, due to this being a virtual subnet, and it's not bridged to the LAN. I get the same results with `\\192.168.x.x\Shared`, using its IPv4 address.

Relevant: I get the same results on the `Accounting` machine itself: in file explorer browsing to `\\Accounting\Shared` works without a password, and shows me the contents of the shared folder on the same machine. But `\\accounting.example.com\Shared`, or `\\192.168.x.x\Shared` results in the same failure: password prompt, then access denied.  This pretty much rules out any networking/firewall issues from the other guest VM, `Accounting` can't browse itself using its own DNS name or IP address.

In the network adapter setting file and printer sharing is enabled.

My Microsoft login/password is valid, no issues logging in on accounts.microsoft.com, from either machine.

I verified in Network Sharing that the `Accounting` machine has the IP address assigned to `accounting.email-scan.com`.

Do I need to do ...something, to allow browsing public shares via DNS name?

Comment: Best to use a Bridged Connection to be able to access a VM from another machine. Use the NET USE command to map a folder and see what the numerical error is. Here is a connection another machine and I used bridged networking.   https://superuser.com/questions/1660364/how-to-connect-via-rdp-to-my-hyper-v-machine/1660424#1660424

Answer (score 0):

Check if **SMB** server iz enabled on both computers. Run `Get-SmbServerConfiguration` command in **PowerShell** and check if `EnableSMB2Protocol` is set to **true**. If it is set to **false** then run command `Set-SMBServerConfigutation -EnableSMB2Protocol $true`.

And make sure the both computers are in the same Workgroup.